# More conditions while using the min() or max() in XPath 2.0

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

Why do we get an error when trying to use the Union operator along with the 'min()' or 'max()' functions in XPath 2.0? The XML I am dealing with has an object named 'quantity' that takes the form like:

```
<quantity>
  <new>
  <value>
  18.0
  </value>
  </new>

  <old>
  <value>
  27.5
  </value>
  </old>
</quantity>
```

and sometimes, the quantity object appears like this:

```
<quantity>
  <small>
  14.25
  </small>
</quantity>
```

In cases where the quantity value appears with the 'new' and 'old' combinations, I have to pick the smallest value among them. So, in order to fetch all the desired quantity values, I tried using the following XPath:

def sort = holder.getNodeValues( "//quantity/min(*/@value) | //quantity/small" )

This gave me the error message "**net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of first operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:double**" - when I used the aforementioned XPath in SoapUI.

Can someone please help me why the Union operator is returning an error here? I want the XPath the fetch the quantity values appearing in the XML document; I am required to pick the least value when it appears under more than one tag (example: 'new' and 'old') and pick the value as it is, when it appears as a single value (example: 'small' tag)

Adding a code sample here with all the possible quantity values:

```
<-- Auxillary nodes -->
<quantity>
      <new>
      <value>
      18.0
      </value>
      </new>

      <old>
      <value>
      27.5
      </value>
      </old>
    </quantity>
<-- auxillary nodes -->

<quantity>
  <small>
  14.25
  </small>
</quantity>

<-- auxillary nodes -->

<quantity>
      <weighted>
      <value>
      18.0
      </value>
      </weighted>

      <median>
      <value>
      27.5
      </value>
      </median>

      <gross>
      <value>
      27.5
      </value>
      </gross>
    </quantity>

<-- auxillary nodes -->
```

Comment: Why are people downvoting this question without leaving comments?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation for the union operator (in Saxon)](http://saxon.sourceforge.net/saxon7.9/expressions.html#union) says,

```
Both expressions [the operands] must return sequences of nodes.
```

But, as the error indicates, your first operand returns a double instead (18.0, in this case).

To get what you're looking for, you could change your XPath expression to

```
"min(//quantity/*/value | //quantity/small)"
```

Note that I removed the `@`, since `value` is an element, not an attribute.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but the requirement is to fetch all the quantity values, not the smallest among those. When there are two quantity values in a single object, only at that time, we have to find the smallest value. The modification that you have suggested returns only one value for me, that is the smallest among all the quantity values.Is there any way possible to achieve this?

Comment: The reason why I am specifying the second XPath outside the min() function is because, there is only one quantity value when it appears with the 'small' tag (nothing to compare and pick the lowest among)

So, I have a requirement to choose the lowest value when it appears in multiple instances:

'def sort = holder.getNodeValues( "//quantity/min(*/@value))'

or choose from the XPath below, when the tag value is absent (since we get a null value when a XPath does not exist) :

'def sort = holder.getNodeValues( "//quantity/small" )'

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan: What result do you get when you try the XPath expression I suggested, when you have only one `<quantity>` value with the `<small>` element? `min()` works fine on a nodeset containing only one node. When I test the above XPath, it works fine according to what I understand of your requirements; try it at http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b742c451e1397aeac27bc33964f9de23 If it's giving you a wrong result, please post the input XML, the expression you're using, the exact desired result, and the actual result.

Comment: I got only one value as a result, when I tried the XPath that you suggested. There can be upto 100 or more quantity objects like this in my XML. And I have to pick all the values, which would have been possible with "//quantity/small" if we are dealing with the 'small' tag alone.

But there is a possibility of the value appearing in two tiers (new and old) and I am to pick the smallest of those in that case. So, I have to make the XPath choose the lowest when there are two ranges and pick the value as is, when dealing with a single value. So it is not possible to use min() here?

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan: OK, I had not understood till now that you could have more than one `<quantity>` element. The samples you gave should `<quantity>` as the root element, of which there can be only one. Please edit your question to post a sample with multiple `<quantity>` elements, including a `<small>` and a `<new>` and `<old>`, so that I'm trying to solve the same problem you are.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan: My initial reaction is `//quantity/min(*/value | small)`, but I'd like to test that on an accurate representative sample.

Comment: I have added the structure of the XML that I am dealing with, and the modification like "//quantity/min(*/value | small)" did not work either. It seems that we will not be able to add an alternative XPath when we are dealing with the max() and min() functions?

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan: Thank you for adding a better sample. I'll wrap it in a `<root>` element to make it well-formed XML. When you say "did not work", please tell what happened, and how it differs from what you expected to happen. Don't leave that work to the people trying to help you.

Comment: According to my testing at http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/a7e023b13d7063dc8491c47306020aa7, `//quantity/min(*/value | small)` produces the expected sequence: 18, 14.25, 18. (I had to wrap it in `string()` and `string-join()` for that test, because xpathtester.com doesn't seem to properly display a sequence of numbers when that's the result.) You'll also need to make sure that the `getNodeValues()` method you're using can handle a sequence of numbers.

Comment: I guess I have mentioned what happened when I tried to implement this scenario: I got an error message saying "net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: Required item type of first operand of '|' is node(); supplied value has item type xs:double". But thanks for the update regarding the string-join() function, will try it out and update here shortly

Comment: @Vishuvardhan: You mentioned that error in regard to your original scenario. You're really getting the same error with `//quantity/min(*/value | small)`? That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Yeah that error has got me confounded, and I am helpless. So I guess I have to choose to iterate through all the nodes, which will take up more memory and time. Thanks for the patient replies and guidance :) It sure did help me understand a bit more about XPath.

Comment: @Vishnuvardhan: I have to wonder if there is something wrong in the broader dev/test setup. There's no way, in `//quantity/min(*/value | small)`, that the `|` operator can be getting a double as an operand. It sounds like it's still trying to use `//quantity/min(*/@value) | //quantity/small` or something similar.